# Issues uploading Angular2 Node app to production (AWS Elastic Beanstalk)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, angular, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I wrote a simple app using this Angular2 Quickstart: https://github.com/angular/quickstart

All is well in development mode but once I get to production, I get stuck.

My app is structured as the original quickstart is structured - with most of the files under the app folder.

This node server I run:

```
const express = require('express');     
const app = express();  
const path = require('path');

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 8000));

app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'app')));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html')); 
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log(`App listening on port ${app.get('port')}`);
});
```

Very basic - notice the 2 express static I use - I believe it is related to my issues.

Beside the server, everything is more or less like the quickstart.

Once I upload to production using AWS Elastic Beanstalk, I get the following error:

"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

http://.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/app/main.js - Not found.
How come my file is not found? What do I have to change in order for it to become available?

I've wasted a lot of times on this so hopefully one of you can help here.
Thanks.

Comment: `main.js` is a source file? If so, you should be getting a 404. Node should not serve it up. What happens if you just go to `/` or `/app` ?

Comment: When I go to /app I get a - 403 Forbidden error. Why is it forbidden? In the server I mentioned I want it as static. I also added it as a static path in my EBS config.